# MakeHuman model physical unit

Tags: makehuman

Does MakeHuman exported model have a physical unit (mm, cm, m, inch, etc.)?

For instance, I expoerted an adult MH model, and measure the distance in a 3D viewer software, the body height is about 53, what could be the proper unit? Or makehuman does not have a unit?